# I have 2 second execution time of my Query but I want it 0 second Execution Time

Tags: sql-server

I want to improve my execution time

```
WITH a2019
AS (
    SELECT sum(line.Amount) AS SaleIn2019
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
    INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
    WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
        AND line.Type = 2
        AND year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2019
    )
    ,a2018
AS (
    SELECT sum(line.Amount) AS SaleIn2018
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
    INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
    WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
        AND line.Type = 2
        AND year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2018
    )
    ,a2017
AS (
    SELECT sum(line.Amount) AS SaleIn2017
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
    INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
    WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
        AND line.Type = 2
        AND year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2017
    )
    ,a2016
AS (
    SELECT sum(line.Amount) AS SaleIn2016
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
    INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
    WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
        AND line.Type = 2
        AND year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2016
    )
    ,a2015
AS (
    SELECT sum(line.Amount) AS SaleIn2015
    FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
    INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
    WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
        AND line.Type = 2
        AND year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2015
    )
SELECT SaleIn2019
    ,SaleIn2018
    ,SaleIn2017
    ,SaleIn2016
    ,SaleIn2015
FROM a2019
    ,a2018
    ,a2017
    ,a2016
    ,a2015
```

Comment: could you please use some white space, new lines, and indentation to make this query readable.

Comment: that very much depends on your database - its schema, indexes, etc. can you generate an execution plan and attach it? in SSMS, you can do that by pressing CTRL+L to run an "estimated execution plan" for your query.

Comment: You could improve this pretty easily by doing this in a single query instead on for each year.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg Its Nav Dynamics Database And I dont have access to that you are asking for,
all I just have this query to share nothing else, If you can rearrange the query in a way that it should improve execution time, I will be very thankful to you

Comment: @SeanLange can you do that for me?

Comment: Why is 2 seconds unacceptable for a query that returns five years of summarized sales data?  Regardless, without the information that Jeff and Sean have requested, I don't think there's much anyone here can do to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much simpler version. And in the future even if you can't get an execution plan posting table definitions, including indexes, is a huge help.

Notice the where clause. It is using dates instead of a function to keep it SARGable.

```
SELECT sum(case when year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2019 then line.Amount end) AS SaleIn2019
    , sum(case when year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2018 then line.Amount end) AS SaleIn2018
    , sum(case when year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2017 then line.Amount end) AS SaleIn2017
    , sum(case when year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2016 then line.Amount end) AS SaleIn2016
    , sum(case when year(header.[Posting Date]) = 2015 then line.Amount end) AS SaleIn2015
FROM [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Header] header
INNER JOIN [Uneek Clothing Company Ltd$Sales Invoice Line] line ON header.No_ = line.[Document No_]
WHERE header.[Sell-to Customer No_] = 'WOR07'
    AND line.Type = 2
    and header.[Posting Date] >= '20150101'
    and header.[Posting Date] < '20200101'
```

Comment: this is slower than mine

Comment: Well without table definitions and indexes this is guessing.